# How to get more info about failed request

Tags: php, http

this is the error message I get:

**Warning**:  file_get_contents(http://example.com/.../asoplayhd2.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in **/home/dttrading/qtech.sk/static/agem_images_download.php** on line **40**

Is there any way to find out more information about why the request has failed?

Comment: if something met timeout or the connection has been refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using curl

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```